# Filtros no Web Panel

Tags: aplicação-web, genexus, panel

Eu fiz uma aplicação para gerenciar todos os equipamentos de TI de uma empresa, eu consigo listar quantos de cada tipo de equipamento existem no total, e também consigo mostrar só um tipo especifico, como notebooks ou desktops, mas não consigo fazer uma listagem mostrando quantos notebooks ou impressoras eu tenho em certa filial. (irei anexar prints).
Gostaria de que quando eu digitasse o nome de certa filial no segundo campo, só aparecesse os equipamentos daquela filial.

Esse é o código do meu Event Load no Web Panel na aba Events

```
Event Load
    &EquipQtn = count(Nome_Equipamento)
    &FilialStartCheck = (Nome_Filial)
EndEvent
```

Esse é o código do meu Grid no Web Panel

```
TipoEquipamentoNome like '%'+&EquipStartCheck.Trim()+'%';
Nome_Filial like '%'+&FilialStartCheck.Trim()+'%';
```

[image: Listagem]

Answer (score 0):

A primeira questão a verificar é se essa GRID é baseada em atributos ou variáveis somente. Quando a GRID é baseada em atributo o evento LOAD executa por linha, quando a GRID é baseada em variáveis somente o evento LOAD é executado apenas uma vez, isso deve ser levado em consideração no seu For each.

Existe algumas maneiras de realizar o count condicionalmente. Você pode fazer um for each manualmente filtrando a filial, ou mesmo buscar este valor de uma procedure ou um data provider. Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

```
Event Load
&count.SetEmpty()
For Eeach
    where Nome_Filial like '%'+&FilialStartCheck.Trim()+'%' WHEN not &FilialStartCheck.IsEmpty()

   &count += 1
EndFor
&EquipQtn = &count
&FilialStartCheck = (Nome_Filial) 
EndEvent
```

Qualquer dúvida só comentar.